# Cygwin Not Showing Any Output in C

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I wrote this code in Sublime:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Saved it at *C:\cygwin64\home\user* as *helloworld.c*.

Typed in this on Cygwin64 Terminal:
`$ gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c`

[But I'm not seeing any output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBs6x.png) Please help.

Comment: Program termination should any flush the FDs, but does adding a "\n" at the end of hello world string makes any difference?

Comment: Or, an explicit `fflush(stdout);` after the print statement?

Comment: Well, you tell us, that you saved it as *.cpp and compiled a *.c file? Something is off here, please clarify.

Comment: You probably forgot to type `./helloword` after the compilation process. The commands you showed _compile_ your program, but you also need to _execute_ it.

Comment: Please don't tag your IDE or code editor unless your question is specifically related to the editor itself.

Comment: @BallisticTomato that was a typo, my file extension is .c

Comment: @jabberwocky Thanks that solved the problem.

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks I'll take care of it in the future.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I simply copied the program from my book, hence the ```/n```. I wonder why it doesn't add a new line before *Hello World*. Any idea?

Comment: @Debol please ask a new question about that specific problem you have

Comment: What output would you expect? If compilation does not find an error, you don't get any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows executable can be obtained by: `$ ./helloworld`